# display data from another activity to another. from class to array list to linearlayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-linearlayout

The code for each part is displayed below.

This is the class wherein the arraylist gets its data from

```
package kfc.project;

public class Product {


    String name;
    int servingSize;
    int calories;
    int fat;
    int saturatedFat;
    int transFat;
    int cholesterol;
    int sodium;
    int carbs;
    int protein;


    public Product (String name, int servingSize, int calories, int fat, int saturatedFat, int transFat, int cholesterol, int sodium, int carbs, int protein){
        this.name=name;
        this.calories=calories;
        this.servingSize=servingSize;
        this.fat=fat;
        this.saturatedFat=saturatedFat;
        this.transFat=transFat;
        this.cholesterol=cholesterol;
        this.sodium=sodium;
        this.carbs=carbs;
        this.protein=protein;
    }

    public Product (String name, int servingSize){
        this.name=name;
        this.servingSize=servingSize;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getServingSize() {
        return servingSize;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public int getFat() {
        return fat;
    }

    public int getSaturatedFat() {
        return saturatedFat;
    }

    public int getTransFat() {
        return transFat;
    }

    public int getCholesterol() {
        return cholesterol;
    }

    public int getSodium() {
        return sodium;
    }

    public int getCarbs() {
        return carbs;
    }

    public int getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }


}
```

This is the array list for the products which gets the parameters above

```
package kfc.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductList {
    ArrayList<Product> list;


    public ProductList (){
        list = new ArrayList<Product>();

        //CREATE PRODUCT HERE
        Product chicken;
        list.add(new Product("ChickenTest",99));    

        Product rice;
        list.add(new Product("RiceTest",11));
    }

    public String[] getNames (){
        int c = 0;
        int size = list.size() - 1;
        String[] names = new String[size];

        while (size >= c) {
            //names.add(list.get(c).getName());
            names[c] = list.get(c).getName();
            c++;
        }

        c = 0;

        return names;
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getList (){
        return list;
    }

}
```

The list view java file to make it visible to the xml file which is already working

```
package kfc.project;

public class ProductListView extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ProductList pl = new ProductList();

        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, PRODUCTS));
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, R.layout.list_item, pl.getList() ));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            startActivity(new Intent("kfc.project.PRODUCTDETAIL"));
          }

        });

    }



    //TEST STRING ARRAY
    static String[] PRODUCTS = new String[] {
        "Chicken", "Rice", "Coke", "Chicken Burger"
    };



}
```

The xml file. This is where i want the data from the class displayed dynamically whenever it is clicked from the list view so the data is dynamic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top|center"
  android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"      
                android:background="@drawable/button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="ADD TO MENU" android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="4sp" android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:background="@drawable/button2"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"   
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="GET TOTAL" android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="15sp" android:paddingTop="10sp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Serving Size: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>
          <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

    </TableLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left">

    </TableRow>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Amount Per Serving: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calories:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="% Daily Value:          "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="35"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="60"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Saturated Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="34"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Trans Fat:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="53"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cholesterol:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sodium:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView26"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Carbohydrate:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="200"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Dietary Fiber:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView28"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="34"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="       Sugars:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView29"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="16"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Protein:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" />
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vitamin A: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="   Vitamin C: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calcium: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="35"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="   Iron: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have to display the class values on top to the xml file whenever a specific array is clicked from the list view

Comment: I'm afraid you have to rephrase a bit... Your requirement is a bit confusing. So you want to fill a listview with values from an arraylist or you want to inflate something programmatically to screen using linear layouts?

Comment: the listview already has values from the class. I want these values to show up in the linear layout yes programatically :)

Comment: I think you need to reword this question and title, it's clear that the community is having problems parsing it due to the amount of code and lack of precise description as to the desired result. When you've done that flag to re-open.

Comment: im getting great help from amy tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Product",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Product product = pl.getList().get(position);
        System.out.println("getName() : "+product.getName());


        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductListView.this, ProductDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", product.getName());
              //Add other values alos in Extras....

        ProductListView.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

From the product object obtained, all the values of that product can be accessed. While calling the next Activity, pass these values in Extras and use them in the product details activity.

**ProductDetails.class**

Set the xml as the content of the ProductDetails activity and get the details passed over Intent in the onCreate() of the activity. These values could be set to the TexViews in the xml.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_details);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = extras.getString("name");

        if (name  != null) {
            TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            text1.setText(name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks amy can you help me further ill send you the file.

Comment: Please tell me what is that you need to do further?

Comment: i cant seem to understand the intent part

Comment: what do i put in the xml file

Comment: how do i pass the values in extras thno

Comment: i already used the code now what how do i call them in extras so i can put it in the label

Comment: i think im on the right track on this amy. thanks but i need to know whats next

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it. There are many tutorials available on using Intents (like this : http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/39467.aspx).

Comment: I have edited the answer once again because I haa added the wrong cast to the TextView. Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: thank you. I tried it i get a forced close why is that

Comment: Where di u get the force close? Please check the logcat and tell me the exception and at which line.

Comment: it says it is due to a null pointer exception

Comment: 11-30 19:50:14.080: W/dalvikvm(443): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kfc.project/kfc.project.productdetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

Comment: To which TextView do you want to set the String? Check if textView2 is there in your xml. If not give an available textView item id in findViewByID at **TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);**

Comment: 11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-30 19:50:14.090: E/AndroidRuntime(443):  at

Comment: the error log is too long i cant post it comploetely

Comment: Also please make sure that your new activity **ProductDetails** is added in the manifest file.

Comment: <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

this is the text view xml. yes i already have the productdetails.xml its working before

Comment: the xml works when i remove the code you gave me and just enter the default activity

Comment: Default activity? At which line do you get the NullPointer exception?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(452): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 19:52:52.350: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 19:52:52.350: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at kfc.project.productdetail.onCreate(productdetail.java:19)
11-30 19:52:52.350: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-30 19:52:52.350: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Comment: **productdetail.java:19** Which is that line in your code? Also just try to clean the project from Project --> Clean option in Eclipse.

Comment: the if statemtn i guess

 String name = extras.getString("name");
  
  if (name != null) {
   TextView text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.servingsize);
   text1.setText(name);
  }

Comment: i tried removing the if statement still gets the same error

Comment: This **TextView text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.servingsize);** should be your problem. Change the cast from EditText to TextView. I had mentioned it in one of the earlier comments.

Comment: did you see the xml file is that okay to have a android:text=""

Comment: i changed it to TextView still get the same error tho

Comment: That is not an issue. But there is no need of that if you are setting the TextView text programatically. Please change the cast and try. And are you sure to have a TextView with id servingsize in your xml?

Comment: yes its now   String name = extras.getString("name");
  
  if (name != null) {
   TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.servingsize);
   text1.setText(name);
  }

Comment: yes its             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/servingsize"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

Comment: Did u try cleaning the project? Extended discussions in comments are not allowed in Stackoverflow. Since you don't have enough reputation chat is also not available.

Comment: okay i cleaned up the project. i think i get an error because of the if statement without an else?

Comment: is there anyother way that im getting this error? maybe past codes

Comment: Did u check the value of name? if statement without an else block shouldn't be a problem.